# Combine multiple SQL queries with having limit

Tags: mysql, sql, join

This is my table

[**DB -Fiddle Link**](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7srXHcJaNt8XRx5UGSVZxY/0) Also a **[SQL FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a9621/1)** LINK

```
`id`, `pname`, `comapny_id`, `premium`
(1, 'aaaa', 1, '1'),
(2, 'bbbb', 1, '2'),
(3, 'cccc', 1, '3'),
(4, 'dddd', 1, '2'),
(5, 'eeee', 1, '1'),
(6, 'ffff', 1, '3'),
(7, 'gggg', 1, '3'),
(8, 'hhhh', 1, '2'),
(9, 'iiii', 1, '1'),
(10, 'jjjj', 1, '2');
```

I want to combine 3 queries.

I tried

```
SELECT *
FROM query_test 
WHERE company_id = 1 AND premium = 1 
LIMIT 3 
INNER JOIN query_test ON SELECT * FROM query_test WHERE company_id = 1 AND premium = 2 LIMIT 4;
```

But that does not work for me. How can I join the following three queries using [SQL join](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_join)? I am learning SQL join from W3Schools.

Query #1:

```
SELECT * 
FROM query_test 
WHERE company_id = 1 AND premium = 1 
LIMIT 3
```

Query #2:

```
SELECT * 
FROM query_test 
WHERE company_id = 1 AND premium = 2 
LIMIT 4
```

Query #3:

```
SELECT * 
FROM query_test 
WHERE company_id = 1 AND premium = 3 
LIMIT 3
```

How can I achieve that with minimum time consumption?

Help should be appreciated.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: but ther is limit in all query

Comment: Please provide [mcve] in the body of the question. LInks to external sites may not exist in the future. You should be able to create an example of the table(s) to include in the Question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `LIMIT` with `UNION`, with proper syntax:

```
(SELECT * FROM query_test WHERE comapny_id = 1 AND premium = 1 LIMIT 3)
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM query_test WHERE comapny_id = 1 AND premium = 2 LIMIT 4)
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM query_test WHERE comapny_id = 1 AND premium = 3 LIMIT 3);
```

Comment: Not working . And Why The above answer is upvoted when it is not working

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax;syntax to use near `'t
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM query_test WHERE comapny_id = 1 AND premium = 3 LIM' at line 4`

Comment: @WebsterTP My updated answer should work now, please try it.

Comment: Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: You can use sql fiddle for test. Thankyou

Comment: @WebsterTP Hopefully you can see why so many people botched the syntax.  We don't do this very often, and even some documentation can be unclear about it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`UNION`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html)

> UNION is used to combine the result from multiple SELECT statements into a single result set.

```
SELECT * FROM query_test WHERE comapny_id = 1 AND premium = 1 LIMIT 3
UNION
SELECT * FROM query_test WHERE comapny_id = 1 AND premium = 2 LIMIT 4
UNION
SELECT * FROM query_test WHERE comapny_id = 1 AND premium = 3 LIMIT 3;
```

Comment: @WebsterTP There is some issue with Fiddle, Above code works in MySql. Test once over there

Comment: I Have tried in my phpmyadmin that is bit work and gives above error\

Comment: Why dont you use sqlfiddle or dbfiddle given by questionner

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way is to use UNION

```
    (SELECT * FROM query_test WHERE comapny_id = 1 AND premium = 1 LIMIT 3)
    UNION
    (SELECT * FROM query_test WHERE comapny_id = 1 AND premium = 2 LIMIT 4)
    UNION
    (SELECT * FROM query_test WHERE comapny_id = 1 AND premium = 3 LIMIT 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try By this

```
SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT * FROM query_test WHERE comapny_id = 1 AND premium = 1 LIMIT 2) AS G 
UNION ALL 
    (SELECT * FROM query_test WHERE comapny_id = 1 AND premium = 2 LIMIT 2) 
UNION ALL 
    (SELECT * FROM query_test WHERE comapny_id = 1 AND premium = 3 LIMIT 2)
```

*Its working and tested.!*